# write into input-hidden-field using jquery

Tags: jquery, events, click, interaction

hey there i have this little script:

http://jsfiddle.net/tr0y/6KNRc/

But instead of displaying the "data-id" in the frontend, i want it to be saved in an input-hidden-field, so i added:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dump" id="dump" value="">
```

when i submitted the form, i did:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

there was just an empty array,so.. how to do that? greetings

Comment: There is no form in that fiddle. Could you show us where is the form and how are you submitting it? Also, add that hidden input to the fiddle so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: here is with form: http://jsfiddle.net/6KNRc/5/ thats exactly how its on my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6KNRc/10/

Use this:

```
$('#dump').val( JSON.stringify(data) );
```

in place of:

```
$('#dump').text( JSON.stringify(data) );
```

Use jquery's [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to change input values. Use text() to change the text of elements. Since inputs don't have text, it wasn't working for you.

Comment: Please accept/upvote if this worked for you. Unless you accept the answer, users logging in now will see it as unanswered ans waste their time.

Answer (score 0):

you have not closed the tags of input `/>`

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit'] == "send") { 
var_dump($_POST);
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="dump" id="dump" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"/>
</form>

    <ul class="ui-selectable">
<li data-id="1"></li>
<li data-id="2"></li>
<li data-id="3"></li>
<li data-id="4"></li>
<li data-id="5"></li>
<li data-id="6"></li>
<li data-id="7"></li>
<li data-id="8"></li>
<li data-id="9"></li>
<li data-id="10"></li>
</ul>


$('#dump').val( JSON.stringify(data) );

the input has property name 'Value' that countains the data
```

Comment: Closing the input tag is not required in HTML. That is an XHTML requirement and browsers work perfectly fine without closing the tag.